# How to hide ng repeat with ng if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have my own autocomplete, I use ng repeat to display the suggestion, to make it like a real autocomplete, I use ng click to change the value for the textbox, but when I click or the value of textbox already same as the suggestion, this suggestion didn't disapear. How do I use ng if in this code? and this is my code
for HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="add.email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off"/>
<div href="#" ng-repeat="x in cobas | filter:add.email" ng-click="autocomplete(x.name)" ng-if="isDisplayed">
 <div class="media-body" ng-if="add.email.length > 0">
  <h5 class="list-group-item media">{{x.name}}
 </div>
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
 $scope.cobas = [
   {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
   {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
   {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
   {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
   {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
   {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
   {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
   {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
   {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
   {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
 ];

$scope.autocomplete = function (completeText){
     $scope.add.email = completeText;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an extra check to see if the value in input is equal to the value in the dropdown.

`ng-if="add.email.length > 0 && add.email != x.name"`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom filter for it and do not use ng-if inside ng-repeat.
I think that the filter is a good place to put this logic.

For example it could be like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('myFilter', function(){    
    return function(items, filter){
        if(!filter) return items;

        var arrayToReturn = [];
        filter = filter.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            var name = item.name.toLowerCase();
            if(!filter || name.substring(0, filter.length) === filter && name !== filter)
                arrayToReturn.push(item);
        });

        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/788/)